# Benefit of Redis on python application

Tags: database, redis, data-science, data-analysis, streamlit

We have a python web application in which we upload data. Web application also performs some analysis on that data based on the options we give. In the end, application gives prepared and analyzed output data back to user. Will in this case can the redis cache makes things faster in terms of data upload, download and analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

Redis just caches any data. All the database calls are costly. If you have a application where you are making multiple calls to database or circumstances where you have done and large computation then you can store it in cache for faster acesss

You also can set the expiry for certain time when you want to expire.

In your case , you can store the computed data in redis for some certain time, and if you are using user login you also can store the auth .